# Playframework 2.3x: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result])play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]

Tags: mongodb, scala, compiler-errors, playframework-2.3

i am trying to run `async` action in play framework and using reactive mongo for database operations. Reactive mongo return results in `Future` objects. But when i return the Future results in action, i am getting compile time error. Play and Scala is new for me, and still not getting what the actual problem is?. I have another code, the code work successfully.

Working code:

```
def dashboard = Action.async{
  logger.info("In dashboard controller method");

  var cursor: Cursor[Playlist] = playlistCollection.find(Json.obj("isPublished"-> true)).sort(Json.obj("htiCount"-> -1)).cursor[Playlist];
  val playlistList : Future[List[Playlist]] = cursor.collect[List]();
  playlistList.map { users => Ok(Json.toJson(users)) }
```

}

Error code:

```
def playlistVideos(plalistId: String) = Action.async{
  logger.info("In playlistVideos controller method");

  var objectIds: List[JsObject] = CustomUtility.convertStringIdToJsonCriteria(List{plalistId});
  var query = Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$in" -> objectIds))
  val cursor: Cursor[Playlist] = playlistCollection.find(query).cursor[Playlist];
  val futurePlayList: Future[Option[Playlist]] = cursor.headOption;
  var bsonIds: Future[List[BSONObjectID]] = futurePlayList.map { option => {
      var playlist: Playlist = option.get;
      var optionVideos: Option[List[BSONObjectID]] = playlist.linkedVideoIds;
      optionVideos.getOrElse(List[BSONObjectID]());
  }}

  bsonIds.map { ids => {
     var videosList: List[String] = ids.map { idObj => idObj.stringify }
     var videosIds:List[JsObject] = CustomUtility.convertStringIdToJsonCriteria(videosList);

     query = Json.obj("linkedVideoIds" -> Json.obj("$in" -> objectIds));
     val videosCursor: Cursor[Video] = videosCollection.find(query).cursor[Video];
     val futureVideos: Future[List[Video]] = videosCursor.collect[List]();

     futureVideos.map { videos => Ok(Json.toJson(videos)) }
  }}
}
```

Following is my compile time error.

```
overloaded method value async with alternatives: [A](bodyParser: play.api.mvc.BodyParser[A])(block: play.api.mvc.Request[A] ⇒ scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result])play.api.mvc.Action[A] <and> (block: play.api.mvc.Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] ⇒ 

scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result])play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] <and> (block: ⇒ scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result])play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] cannot be applied to (scala.concurrent.Future[scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bsonIds is future and futureVideos also a future, So the last line will be Future[Future[_]].

So change,  `bsonIds.map { ids =>` to `bsonIds.flatMap{ ids =>`

Comment: Hello @SKarthik again thanks to you. This is work for me. Please suggest me, from where i learn good, Play and Scala ?

Comment: Refer this link for scala : http://danielwestheide.com/scala/neophytes.html. also learn about implicits, Monads and for comprehension with monads

Comment: Thanks @ S Karthik and where i found good knowledge for Play ?